# How to create storm / lightning strike effect in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I would like to create lightning strike effect in some specific area or even better in specific points (starting and ending of lightning strike). I tried to follow example: [webgl_lightningstrike](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lightningstrike.html) from three.js

I stuck in the place in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/storm-6hgyg?file=/src/App.js) does anyone figure out how to use it with three fiber I would very appreciate for any advice how to move forward.

Comment: I´m also looking for the same thing.

Comment: Same here. Wondering how to do it in react three